# Turn digits before a certain character into a separate object

Tags: python, formatting

I have an object defined as some numbers, a forward slash surrounded by spaces and then also some numbers, and I want to turn the digits before the forward slash into a separate object. Here are some examples:

```
4026 / 1769395
5160 / 1769395
5158 / 1769395
```

The examples are the content of different cells in an HTML table that I got by using this code ('curver' and 'curcol' are variables defining the verse and column of the cell that is in use):

```
cellcontent = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table[8]/tbody/tr[' + str(curver - 3) +']/td[' + str(curcol + 1) + ']').text

print(cellcontent)
```

I know that it looks like the easier approach is to just include only the first four digits, or include everything except the last 10 digits, but the examples look like this because of the dataset I'm testing the code with. Sometimes there can be less or more digits in the first or the second number.

How can I include only the numbers before a space and a forward slash?

Comment: Can you provide code showing what objects (before an after) you are talking about?

Comment: What `object` are you using? If it's equivalent to a string, the `split()` method should do what you're asking. If not, then perhaps implementing a version of the `string.split()` method on your object would work? In any case, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with enough detail for us to know how to help you

Comment: so you want to separate the first and the second string to generate int values?

Comment: To mark the question as solved click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. (Don't put SOLVED in the title.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as simple as:

```
string = '4026 / 1769395'
#Remove the int if you dont actually need them as numbers but as string.
first_digits = int(string.split(' / ')[0])
```

Also if you are working with dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['4026 / 1769395'],
                   ['5160 / 1769395'],
                   ['5158 / 1769395']], columns=['column_1'])

df['first_digits'] = df.column_1.apply(lambda x: x.split(' / ')[0])

df['second_digits'] = df.column_1.apply(lambda x: x.split(' / ')[1])

df
```

Output:

```
      column_1    first_digits  second_digits
0   4026 / 1769395   4026      1769395
1   5160 / 1769395   5160      1769395
2   5158 / 1769395   5158      1769395
```